# CSS padding inside nested div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out why the box in this fiddler has so much padding above and below the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/fZ6d7/1/

**CODE**

```
 <style>
    .simplebox {
        padding: 6px;
        background: #eee;
        border-radius: 8px;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #fff inset, 0 -1px 0px #ccc inset;
    }
     .simplebox-content {
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #ddd inset;
        border: 1px solid #cccccc;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #fff;
        padding: 0 8px;
    }
    </style>


    <div class="simplebox" data-editurl="/TextualReporting/ShowProgressEditor?itemId=5d205a60-64de-4717-ac1d-9db00189db74" style="">
    <div class="simplebox-content">
    <p>This is a test. This text has too much padding above and below.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Any insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is the default padding and margin! You can use this basic universal reset to remove all default padding and margin for all of your html elements:

```
* { padding: 0; margin 0;}
```

Add it to the very top of your css stylesheet, that way nothing will have padding unless you specify it. So your `<p></p>` (or any others) wont have that pesky default margin.

Using some form of resets is a front end best practice. Interested in more advanced resets? Check out [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/).

Example in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/agconti/SLjV2/2/

Answer (score 2):

Paragraph `<p>` has got margin by default :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the `<p>` tag which has some margin as a standard. To remove it merely add

```
p {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

to your css... or alternatively use another tag.